# php mysql select columns where their value it is smaller than current time (timestamp)

Tags: mysql

ok, so what i am trying to do is a simple task, but still i don't get it. 
I want to select from a MySql table just the rows that their "last_action" column value is smaller than current time (timestamp generated by php function time() )

it's obvious that all the values previously inserted are smaller than current time :), but i don't know why my simple script doesn't trust "my instinct" :)

here is my php function written in CODEIGNITER, it's not big deal, the query it's important:

```
function get_exp_sessions(){
    $time = time();
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM session WHERE last_action < "$time"');

    echo $query->num_rows();
}
```

the result i get is ZERO.

if i put

```
last_action > $time
```

i get "3"

i don't get it...

Comment: How are they inserted? Are you using PHP `time()` or MySQL `NOW()`? Does the server timezone _match_ the timezone registered as `date_default_timezone` in php.ini?

Comment: Also, is `last_action` an INT column in MySQL, or is it a `DATETIME` which would need to be converted when compared with PHP's timestamp?

Comment: when i insert the timestamp i use php time(). last_action is set as INT.the timezone i don't know if it's important 'cause all my actions are made from the same machine, same server. I even compared the numbers looking in my database and echo-ing the current timestamp. for sure the values from the database are smaller.

Comment: MySQL should do this for you, but to make sure, you are using `"` around the timestamp, which would indicate a string, strictly speaking "1" is not 1

Comment: @user348078 It is a matter of quoting. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see it.  Your quoting is incorrect.  You have single quotes on the outer string, which cause the variable `$time` not to be interpolated in the string and instead passed literally as `$time`.

The literal string value `$time` gets cast to an integer by MySQL, and any non-numeric string will cast to zero.

MySQL is executing:

```
SELECT * FROM session WHERE last_action < 0
```

Switch the quotes - it is good practice and most portable to use single quotes around the variable in the SQL anyway, and indeed since it is an integer value generated by `time()` (known not to require escaping), it needn't be quoted.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM session WHERE last_action < $time");
```

Though not absolutely necessary in this case, this would have been avoidable if `$time` had been bound as a parameter in Codeigniter instead of passed directly to the query.

Comment: @user348078 Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php